# Less changes does not apply

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, less

ASP.NET MVC4. I'm using Less in my project. On my domestic computer browser does not see any changes in .less files. 
For example
    HTML:

```
 <div class="someClass"></div>
```

.less file(old one):

```
.someClass{
//rule1
}
```

Browser sees rule 1.
Then I add rule 2(update old from my domestuc computer).

```
.someClass{
    //rule1
    //rule2
    }
```

Browser does not see rule2.
Cache is disabled. ctrl+F5 does not help
Tried different browsers
On my work computer everthing is fine, but not on domestic

Here's web.comfig:

```
<handlers>
      <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
</handlers>
```

Here's Core.less where I add all .less files:

```
/*Imports*/
@import "Global_classes";
@import "Global";
@import "Mixins";
//import all pages .less
```

Comment: Are you recompiling the .less file(s)? Are you using content bundling in the ASP.NET application?

Comment: Try changing the name of the file. Like adding a version each time you compile. I'm not sure if like adding dumb params would work. like adding "?ver=1" at the end of the url or #ver1. Pretty sure the problem is the filename.

Comment: As it is less i don't attach a link to every page like:                                   
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/Core.css"> So, file names and content bundling are not the reasons

Comment: How do you integrate your less file ? what's the compiler, and where do you add the less/css link ? please edit you post adding more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my VS 2015 and Web Essentials. WE does not compile .less files for VS 2015. 
So the  desicion of the problem was to install [Web-Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler) and [Bundler & Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier)